# Set up App Registration (Azure AD) through code?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, curl, azure-active-directory

I'm working for a company that uses an SSO solution (Auth0) to allow client companies to access our application using their existing logins. Many of our clients are using Azure AD as their authorization server.

We have everything working properly through the azure portal. We set up an App Registration and then use that in our SSO solution (the domain, client id and a generated secret) to connect. That all works well.

However, we have several clients and its become a problem that some of our clients aren't easily able to follow our guidance to set up the app registration, and so we're looking at what steps we might be able to do to automate the process of setting up app registration for them.

We have a couple of scripts already using node to setup other authorization servers (Okta...). We've written those in node, so ideally we'd like to continue that and write a solution to create an app registration (with permissions and generating a key) through javascript.

We are open to using another language (C#?) if required though.
We could easily work from a curl (or other restful interface) example if there is a rest api. Actually if there is a pointer to a rest api that would probably work well.

Anyone have any experience or tutorials in doing this sort of thing? Would love to see a working example.

TLDR looking for tutorial to create app registrations (with permissions and generating a secret key) in node (curl, or maybe C#)

Comment: Hi Chris, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful? If you have have any further concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Graph API: [Create application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create Azure AD application.

See the C# sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples).

Here is a rest sample for your reference:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 67

{
  "displayName": "allentestapp003",
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "465a38f9-76ea-45b9-9f34-9e8b0d4b0b42",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "798ee544-9d2d-430c-a058-570e29e34338",
                    "type": "Role"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You should specify the `requiredResourceAccess` as the permissions of the Azure AD application. (In this sample, the permissions are for Microsoft Graph, `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the app id of Microsoft Graph app)

For generating a secret key, you need to use [application: addPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). See the C# sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples).

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I am doing the same thing.  But I don't know how to create the authProvider.  What I am looking for if even possible.  Is The click a Register App button in my web app.  That with prompt them to log into the Azure AD and request permissions to generate the Azure AD App and then create the secret key.

If anyone has a code sample showing how to do this, it would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: This answer is a variation of the original question.