# Set up App Registration (Azure AD) through code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking to setup a web app that allows the end users to setup SSO, but I am looking for a full code set that show me how to call the Graph API to request an app id and setup the secret key.

I have read the [Set up App Registration (Azure AD) through code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275384/set-up-app-registration-azure-ad-through-code) example but didn't show me how to actually do it.

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused about how to get `authProvider` from the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275384/set-up-app-registration-azure-ad-through-code). See [choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS), more details about library [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth).

**For example** using `ClientCredentialProvider` with application permission:

First type `Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -PreRelease` into the Package Manager Console.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var application = new Application
{
    DisplayName = "Display name"
};

await graphClient.Applications
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(application);
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I understand what the objective is, but I have seen in websites that when you register for SSO it has you sign into Azure and it will auto setup a Azure AD Application ID and Security Key.

To use the above code you would already have had to setup the Application App already which defeats the purpose of setting up another one. Unless I am missing something all together.

Comment: So I am looking for a way to call the API and have it come up with the Microsoft Work/School Login, Then using the API it would ask for permission to add the new Application ID. I have seen it before done this way, I just have no idea how they achieved this.

Comment: It seems you want to sign in with a user and then create an application without App registrations(client-id and client-secret). This is not possible to access the graph api without an app registration, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63026736/13308381).

Comment: You could use Azure CLI [`az ad app create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_create) as a workaround. Make sure the user account you login has the permission.